# Service principal as a O365 group owner

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The administrator has created a O365 group and assigned my application as a service principal as an owner for the group. He also said he had added Mail.Send permission to the application.

I have obtained the access token via client_credentials flow for the application.

I try to send mail but it fails with the following error.

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" --data-binary @email.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UPN>/sendMail

{"error":{"code":"NoPermissionsInAccessToken","message":"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.","innerError":{"oAuthEventOperationId":"...","oAuthEventcV":"...","errorUrl":"https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidGrant","requestId":"...","date":"..."}}}
```

What can be a problem here? What does it even mean that the application (service principal) is an owner of the group? Does it give the app additional permissions? It does not seem like it since the following request also fails:

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupemail@example.com

{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
    "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
    "innerError": {...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Grab the access token and put it in https://jwt.ms and see if you can find something like "roles": Mail.Send

Comment: no, nothing like that.